# Which ML Algorithm should I use to predict a list of events?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm new to data science model selection and I hope you can help on the model selection to my current problem.

I'm trying to predict the list of events based on the categorical features with numerical labels. For example:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 y1 
1   1  3  4  5  Injury
2   2  2  1  3  Flood
3   1  2  3  2  Injury
3   2  1  1  1  Fire
1   1  1  1  1  Protest
```

I like to predict the top 3 events based on the categorical features. I assume it involves probability method in the machine learning, which algorithm / ML / Deep Learning method would you suggest me to use?

Expectation output would be as follows:

```
1. Injury
2. Fire
3. Flood
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have fixed-size input, five categorical variables.

First proposal try to use embedings vectors instead of simple integers for categorical value encoding. The simplest way is use embeding layers and let the network create embedings for [you](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-4-embedding-layers-f9a02d55ac12).

Second proposal, for this purpose seems to me ok use multilayer perceptron or 1D convolution layer(maybe combine both of them). Philosophy should be, you apply your input features, these will be processed following dense or 1D CNNN layers, the output layer will be dense layer. If these are only possible diagnosis

- Injury
- Flood
- Fire
- Protest

Than your output will have 4 units. If you want a list, you may try the treshold approach, so if unit activation passed through the treshold value is considered as part of possible diagnosis list.

About technical aspect you not mention about your background. So I recommend to use some standard ML library tensorflow, pytorch... Is relatively easy to setup and perform experiments.

**Edit**

Network may looks like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units, activation="relu", input_shape=appropriate_shape))
model.add(Dense(output_units, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['acc']))
```

If you construct network at such manner(see softmax at output layer and categorical_crossentropy as loss) network will natural produce probabilities as output. After training, if you use model as:

```
results = model.predict(input_data)
```

Results will be list of lists of probabilities(one list for every input sample). If you calculate sum of one such a list, you get the 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. It is helpful. Let me explain more about the dataset, and the x features value can be the same but has different events of output, hence I mentioned might involved probability algorithm. I like to have the list of outputs go by probability. After some digging, I could use .predict_proba(y) and use the probability ranks as my list of outputs. What do you think? Is there any ml that would be best for a ranking recommendation?

Comment: If you use neural network, activations of output layer will be softmax and loss categorical. crossentropy, than you may interpret outputs as probability.

Comment: Hi, that's a good idea, can you show me the sample to turn the outputs as probability? I get the compile parameter, but not sure how to turn the output as probability. Thanks again.